# QPainter device returned engine == 0, type: 3 (in re-defined paint() method)

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

I have a large piece of Qt-based software which runs just fine on all the modern machines that we are using. We tried to run the compiled software on the older machine, and the software crashes when we try to build bigger scenes with the following set of errors:

[image: error log figure]

There are only couple places in the program where the `QPainter` is used, and  it is within a re-defined method `paint()` of an inherited class of `QStyledItemDelegate`, e.g.:

```
virtual void paint(QPainter *painter, 
                   const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, 
                   const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    // ...
    QApplication::style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_PushButtonLabel, &buttonDelete, painter);
}
```

The question is what could be the reason of such problems with `QPainter`? Could it be something to do with available memory as it seems to be fine on all the modern machines? Any suggestions what can be done here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> older machine

+

> the software crashes when we try to build bigger scenes

= most likely it ran out of memory. You can install an out-of-memory handler to get informed when that happens:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <new>

void my_new_handler()
{
  printf("Memory allocation failed, terminating\n");
  std::set_new_handler(nullptr);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  std::set_new_handler(my_new_handler);
  ...
  return app.exec();
}
```